# How to align case objects with scalafmt?

Tags: scala

I would like to align `case objects` extending some class with `scalafmt`:

```
sealed abstract class AClass(id: String)
object AClass {
  case object Abc  extends AClass("1")
  case object De   extends AClass("2")
  case object Fghi extends AClass("3")
}
```

I have tried the following with in `.scalafmt.conf` with no success:

```
align.tokens=[
  { code = "extends", owner = "case object" }
]
```

What options should I use?

Comment: I would have to ask why you are placing the `case class` definitions in the `object`. You already have a `package` and you've marked the `trait` as `sealed`. There's really no benefit to positioning things this way (and you may encounter some really odd esoteric compiler bugs if you use macros.)

Comment: I have many such enumerations declared in the same file. I wrapped inside the companion object in order to avoir name collisions.

Comment: fwiw, I often do the same nesting thing for the same reason.